# Proper mathematical model for optimization problem: raising stacks of things to equal level

Tags: sorting, modeling

Given **(A)** different and unevenly filled stacks of things(say apples), known amounts **(a)** per stack and **(N)** incoming new apples to be distributed.

I'm looking to maximize the NUMBER of stacks with equal filling, without rearranging the existing apples.

**Is there an existing problem that resembles mine?**

It's somewhat close to partitioning problem and knapsack problem I guess, but none of those quite cuts it for me. I'm trying to avoid quadratic problems, if possible.

Comment: Add the apples, one at a time, each to the smallest stack at that instant?

Comment: That is the go to solution for code, sure. I'm looking for a more theoretical solution to use in linear or mixed integer programming.

Comment: You might get a better answer on a more theoretically-oriented SE such as [CS:SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).